# How to Name Content Pages in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, renaming, content-pages

So I am having some difficulty with Visual Studio. My goal is to set up a master page and have content pages to make sure that the layout is consistent throughout the site.

The Problem:
When I run my file I have this error come up:
[image]

Steps I've Taken so Far:

Website(in the solution explorer)>Add New Item> Choose Web Form> Name it "homePage"> Click choose MasterPage File and choose my Master Page.

I followed the steps in this [forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/886645.aspx?Renaming+Content+Pages) and I am still receiving the Error! I have looked at the code-behind files ad the Inherits match up I am incredibly stuck on this one guys. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Which project template are you using? Also, Web Forms is stone-age technology. Unless you're actually doing forms on the web, be sure to look into more modern approaches.

Comment: show your .aspx page header.. also what is the error that you are getting..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE, the actual error is clearly visible in the provided screenshot. Which error are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message tells you what the problem is.

> Make sure that the class defined in the code file matches the 'inherits' attribute.

Look in your.aspx file.  There should be an `@Page` directive with an `inherits` attribute.  This attribute should be set to your class name, and this is case sensitive.